# python-igraph documentation unavailable

Tags: python, igraph

It seems that the full documentation on classes and functions which I used to access is now removed:
https://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.Graph-class.html
https://igraph.org/python/doc/python-igraph.pdf
I remember these are the most comprehensive resources and wonder if anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Documentation now lives at https://python.igraph.org/

---

You can find the new documentation at https://igraph.org/python/doc/api/index.html. The documentation is currently being revamped, which also meant that some links changed. The problem of the old links was also reported at [this](https://github.com/igraph/python-igraph/issues/374) issue. Some issues around the building of the documentation are being discussed [here](https://github.com/igraph/python-igraph/issues/268).